# How can I make a TextView appear disabled, but still respond to clicks?

Tags: android, textview

I have the following code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

if (condition) {
    tv.setEnabled(false);
}

tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

If `condition` is true, this causes the text to appear in a lighter grey colour but also to stop responding to clicks.

**How can I make the TextView take on the 'disabled' appearance whilst still responding to click events?** I would like to accomplish this without manually adjusting the colours, something like:

```
tv.setEnabled(false);
tv.setClickable(true);
```

(which doesn't work)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can make out, there is not a way to accomplish what I wanted; the appearance of the text must be manually changed so as to match disabled `TextView`s.

Making the text look disabled:

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bbbbbb"));
```

Making the text look enabled:

```
tv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_light));
```

The downside to this approach is that, I imagine, there will be some devices that don't use `#BBBBBB` as the colour for disabled `TextView`s. This means that text adjusted using the above method will not match text adjusted using `setEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making minor mistake.
Try this...

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

if (condition) {
   tv.setEnabled(false);
   tv.setClickable(false);
}

tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

Comment: I want it to remain clickable though! Calling `setEnabled(false)` by itself stops the view from being clickable.

Comment: @Ellis so you want to avoid setEnabled() right?? and just disable the textview but keep it clickable.??

Comment: Basically, yes - I want to change its appearance to how it looks when I use `setEnabled(false)` but still allow for interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but there is a better way to do this, you can use TouchInterceptorLayout.

Just add it to your project, put your `TextView` inside `TouchInterceptorLayout`, make `TextView`'s `setEnabled()` true and set a click listener to the `interceptorLayout`.

You can find the Java - Kotlin classes and XML codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55211290/9330290)