# Android - Make whole search view clickable with query hint

Tags: java, android, searchview

So i've been working on this inventory management system in Android Studio. In the fragment for Product Taking i have a search view and i want to make this search views whole body to be clickable. Part of this problem is solved here: [Android - Make whole search bar clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455723/android-make-whole-search-bar-clickable). But i want the search view to have a visible query hint. So basically i want it to be a button with search icon and a text. I want that because it is supposed to open a dialog where the user actually going to search for products. Not from this search view.
 When i add the setIconified(true) whole body is clickable but query hint is not visible. Like this:
[image]

When i add setIconified(false) query hint is visible but only search icon is clickable. Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept all touches before SearchView consume them. I've created a simple class that intercept all touch events.
Kotlin:

```
class TouchInterceptorLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    // You need override this method.
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Java:

```
public class TouchInterceptorLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public TouchInterceptorLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchInterceptorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchInterceptorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

See how xml looks:

```
<com.example.testci.temp.TouchInterceptorLayout
            android:id="@+id/interceptorLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:queryHint="@string/app_name"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</com.example.testci.temp.TouchInterceptorLayout>
```

Now you need just set `OnClickListener` to `interceptorLayout`.

Full code with my experiment you can find [here](https://github.com/rt1shnik/test_ci/tree/test_search_view).

Comment: I'm using Java and don't know Kotlin at all, is there any chance you can change TouchInterceptorLayout class to Java?

Comment: @MertcanSeğmen I've added Java version of TouchInterceptorLayout.